# Achieve maximum power output of load with this transistor configuration?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transistors, power, current

[image]

**How to achieve Maximum power output of the variable load with this configuration?** I have tried to reduce the load, increase or decrease R43 & R49 but to no avail. Even if you try to increase the 10V supply, the power output of the load will still not get above 5 Watts. **Note that V1 and V2 are both square waves but inverted to each other and the load you can change to whatever value you like**

Thank you for reading
[image]

Comment: What's the load you intend? And what exactly is driving this mess? Seriously, what are the details? I've zero interest in what you have shown... it doesn't make any sense to me. So I don't want to plug a value into it for you. I want to know what you are ***really*** about here. If this is for some class, just say so. But if this is for real, tell us about it. (Or me, anyway. Otherwise, I've no interest at all.)

Comment: @jonk Convert pulse current to oscillating current wave back and forth at the load. That's why you have inverted square wave

Comment: @jonk maybe 10Ohms for the load which has the power of 500Watts

Comment: What is a "pulse current"? And what is an "oscillating current wave back and forth"? Sorry, that doesn't cut it for me as it is. I need to put my head around the entire application space. I need a complete picture of what is going on. Otherwise, no interest here. Someone else can make sense of it. Disclose and open your hand so I can see what you are holding there. The above circuit is completely useless, start to finish.

Comment: @MaximusSu please redraw the schematic so that it follows convention ... Vcc at top ... Gnd at bottom ... input at one side ... output on the other side ... in case of your circuit, inputs on the sides, output (load) in the middle .... when you do this, you may see the problem with the transistors more clearly

Comment: If you want to dissipate maximum power in the load, just connect the load directly to the voltage. The transistors are just getting in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with this circuit.

Let's start with the fact that you have your emitters at a *higher* potential than your collectors. That would be fine for PNP transistors, but not these NPN ones. Either put your power supply voltage sources at the top, connected to the collector side, or change your NPN transistors for PNP.

I'll assume you intended to use NPNs, and the power supply issue is fixed. I'll also assume you intended to employ the transistors as emitter followers, with 10Ω to ground from each emitter. In that configuration you can expect the voltage at the emitters to rise and fall with the corresponding input voltage at the base, but always 0.7V lower.

Each transistor is able to "pull" its emitter potential upwards (towards +10V) very strongly, but you only have 10Ω resistors to pull them back to ground. That's still quite strong, but you'll have to account for this asymmetry in your calculations.

Let's imagine that Q8's base is at 10V. That places its emitter potential (\$V_1\$) at:

$$ V_1 = +10V - 0.7V = +9.3V $$

Simultaneously Q9's base is at 0V, meaning that it is switched fully off, and can be disregarded in calculations. Therefore the right side of the load \$R_{50}\$, is effectively connected only to \$R_{49}\$, and we can focus on the network consisting of \$R_{49}\$ and \$R_{50}\$.

By Ohm's law, we can know the current \$I_{50}\$ through this pair:

$$ I_{50} = \frac{V_1 - 0V}{R_{50} + R_{49}} = \frac{9.3V}{1010\Omega} = 9.2mA $$

We can therefore know the power \$P_{50}\$ dissipated by \$R_{50}\$:

$$ P_{50} = I_{50}^2 \cdot R_{50}  = 9.2mA^2 \times 1000\Omega = 85mW $$

That's the maximum power you can ever expect to dissipate in \$R_{50}\$ when it is 1000Ω, and \$R_{49}\$ is 10Ω.

There's a principle called "[maximum power transfer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem)" which (paraphrased) says that if you have two resistances in series, one being fixed, then maximum power is dissipated in the other when the resistances are equal.

If we say that \$R_{49}\$ is fixed at 10Ω, then we can expect the maximum power delivered to \$R_{50}\$ to be when \$R_{50} = R_{49} = 10\Omega\$.

Let's plug those values into our calculations, and find out what that power is:

$$ I = \frac{9.3V}{R_{50} + R_{49}} = \frac{9.3V}{10\Omega + 10\Omega} = 470mA $$
$$ P_{50(MAX)} = I^2 \cdot R_{50}  = 470mA^2 \times 10\Omega = 2.2W $$

You probably have enough information now to get yourself back on track, but fix your circuit first!

Comment: Hi sir, I hope you are familiar with this inverter circuit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVeERT4nyz8&t=260s. I have actually created a circuit and it works (Convert DC to AC) but the problem is the transistors absorbs too much power than the load does which really reduces efficiency. Do you mind if i share my circuit with you?

Comment: I can also send my LT Spice file if you have LT spice installed on your PC